# Find the coefficients $A_n$ if $T(x, 0) = \sin x \cos x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-series

Given that $T(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin(nx)e^{-n^2t},$ find the coefficient $A_n$ given that $T(0,t)=0=T(\pi,t)$ and that $T(x,0)$.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Use the trigonometric identity $$\sin x \cos x = \dfrac 1 2 \sin(2x)$$ (the double-angle formula for the sine function).

That means only the term $n=2$ is not zero. So $A_2 = \text{ ?}$

Comment: WHy does it mean that only the n=2 term is not zero. And I don't know how to get the value of it

Comment: Using the fourier trick, I've got to $A_m$ = $\frac {1}{4*pi}$($\frac {sin((2+m)x)}{2+m}$ + $\frac {sin((2-m)x}{2-m}$) evaluated between pi and 0

Comment: Your series is $$ A_1\sin(x)e^{-t} + A_2 \sin(2x) e^{-4t} + A_3 \sin(3x) e^{-9t} + A_4 \sin(4x) e^{-16t} + \cdots. $$ When $t=0$ this becomes $$ A_1\sin(x) + A_2 \sin(2x) + A_3 \sin(3x) + A_4 \sin(4x) + \cdots. $$ And you've said this is equal to $\sin x\cos x,$ which is $\dfrac 1 2 \sin(2x).$ Thus it is one term of your series, and it tells you what number $A_2$ is. All the other terms vanish.

Comment: Is it pi/4 ? that i require

Comment: You seem to be making this complicated. $$ A_1\sin(x) + \underbrace{ A_2 \overbrace{\sin(2x)} } + A_3 \sin(3x) + A_4 \sin(4x) + \cdots \quad = \quad \frac 1 2 \overbrace{\sin(2x)} $$

Comment: Why is it only for $A_2$ though, like I used the Fourier trick and am getting a different answer to you. Like the answer has to be 1/4 then, not 1/2

Comment: @DanielMcElroy : Can you be explicit about how you got $1/4 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: No, its a half. I made a mistake with the factor of 2